# How to execute the code by giving it an option to repeat?

Tags: c, execute

In this code, it is not allowing the first code to execute because I want it to give an option if a user further wants to execute and repeat the process again. The second thing is that I want to save it in the *CSV* file again and again if a user typed **y** to save further.

**Code to give an option**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int allowmain(void) {
  char select_option[2];
  int answer = -1;

  while (answer < 0) {
    printf("Do you want it to repeat (y/n)? ");
    if (fgets(select_option, 2, stdin) == NULL)
      break;

    switch (select_option[0]) {
    case 'y':
      answer = 1;
      break;
    case 'n':
      answer = 0;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (answer < 0)
    answer = 0;

  return answer;
}
```

**Code to execute**

```
int main() {
  FILE *fw = fopen("new.csv", "a");
  char data[3][21], input[20];
  int done = 0, repeat = 0;

  while (!done) {

    if (repeat) {
      if (!allowmain())
        break;
    }

    repeat = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      printf("Enter a word: ");
      fgets(data[i], 20, stdin);
    }

    fprintf(fw, "%s %s %s", data[0], data[1], data[2]);
    
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: 2-byte buffer is too short to use with `fgets()` because the 2 bytes will be occupied by newline character and terminating null-character. Allocate more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to extract the main function into its own function. You can wrap that function in a do-while and keep going as long as the `allowmain` returns true:

```c
void write_words() {
  FILE * fw = fopen("new.csv", "a");
  char data[3][21], input[20];

  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    printf("Enter a word: ");
    fgets(data[i], 20, stdin);
  }

  fprintf(fw, "%s %s %s", data[0], data[1], data[2]);
  fclose(fw);
}

int main() {
  do {
    write_words();
  } while (allowmain());
}
```

Comment: On the second time when I write yes to repeat, it just allow to enter word two times.

Comment: Weird, the inner workings of the `write_words` function would not be affected by the outer loop. Is the program's exit code 0?

Comment: I didn't put the exit code. The code is in front of you but it is not executing properly. By giving an option to repeat, it does not work properly. You can check it out yourself.

Comment: The [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) is a number returned by the program when it exits, its also known as exit status sometimes. It indicates whether an error occurred during the execution of the program.

Comment: You should do `fclose(fw);` before returning from `write_words`.